# How to Cache A webpage with Crosswalk?

Tags: android, webview, crosswalk-runtime

According to the doc:
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/apis/embedding_api.html

You can add a flag to indicate if you want to "reload" from cache.

But how can I cache the entire page, so that even after the xwalkView.load can be completed instantly ?